# How to centering cells with these code

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have searched with many solutions about centering the cells. But none of them works with my code. Could you please help a newbie like me.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \label{concent55}
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting}
  \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
    \toprule
          &       & \multicolumn{5}{c}{insti after 1990} \\
    \midrule
          &       &  1     &   2     & 3     & 4     & 5 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{concent}} & 1     & 0.06552 & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 2     & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 3     & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 4     & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 5     & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you be a bit more precise about whom you want to centre? Assuming you want the main cells centred use `c` instead of `r`. If it is only the "headings" 1, 2, ... etc wrap them in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{1}`. Finally, the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in the first column seem a bit superfluous to me.

Comment: Wonderful,,, the 'c' works!

Comment: Be careful that `\label{concent5}` should go *after* the caption.

Answer (score 2):

A version with package `siunitx`. The data numbers are aligned at the decimal marker. The numbers 1, ..., 5 above the floating data numbers can be centered by putting it into braces, then package `siunitx` sets this entry centered regardless of the contents, especially the entry is not parsed and aligned as number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting}
  \label{concent55}
  \begin{tabular}{cr*{5}{S[table-format=1.6]}}
    \toprule
    &   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{insti after 1990} \\
    \midrule
    &   & {1}      & {2}      & {3}      & {4}      & {5}      \\
    \multirow{5}{*}{concent}
    & 1 & 0.06552  & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
    & 2 & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
    & 3 & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
    & 4 & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908  \\
    & 5 & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In this case, `\multirow` is not needed at all. The following example puts `concent` in the middle data row. Also the `\midrule` is truncated to cover the data columns only as in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269057/16967) of Mico.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting}
  \label{concent55}
  \begin{tabular}{cr*{5}{S[table-format=1.6]}}
    \toprule
    &   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{insti after 1990} \\
    \cmidrule{3-7}
    &   & {1}      & {2}      & {3}      & {4}      & {5}      \\
    & 1 & 0.06552  & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
    & 2 & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
    concent
    & 3 & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
    & 4 & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908  \\
    & 5 & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Now an experiment with one single vertical line and rotated `concent` follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting}
  \label{concent55}
  \begin{tabular}{c|r*{5}{S[table-format=1.6]}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    &   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{insti after 1990} \\
    \cmidrule{3-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    &   & {1}      & {2}      & {3}      & {4}      & {5}      \\
    & 1 & 0.06552  & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
    & 2 & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{concent}}
    & 3 & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
    & 4 & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908  \\
    & 5 & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with rotated "concent" and vertical line]

Without vertical line:

> [image: Result without vertical line]

In the following examples, "concent" is moved to the position of the column header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting}
  \label{concent55}
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format=1.0]
    *{5}{S[table-format=1.6]}
  }
    \toprule
    {concent} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{insti after 1990} \\
    \midrule
      & {1}      & {2}      & {3}      & {4}      & {5}      \\
    1 & 0.06552  & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
    2 & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
    3 & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
    4 & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908  \\
    5 & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Different position of `\midrule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting}
  \label{concent55}
  \begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format=1.0]
    *{5}{S[table-format=1.6]}
  }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{insti after 1990} \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    {concent}  & {1}      & {2}      & {3}      & {4}      & {5}      \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0.06552  & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
    2 & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
    3 & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
    4 & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908  \\
    5 & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Please, fix the position of `\label`

Comment: The directive `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{concent}}` can be simplified to `\multirow{5}{*}{concent}`.

Comment: @egreg Ups, overlooked.

Comment: @Mico Of course, the optional argument with the default value can be removed. The `\multicolumn` can be removed, if this remains as only entry in the first column or if the table column type is changed accordingly. I have now applied these changes.

Comment: thx, good buddie

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses the `dcolumn` package and its `d` column type to align the numbers on their decimal markers.

Note that the four `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` directives are not needed and that `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[0]{*}{concent}}` may be simplified to `\multirow{5}{*}{concent}`. Separately, the `\label` directive must come *after* the `\caption` statement if you intend to cross-reference this table elsewhere in your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} % alignment on decimal marker
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Sorting} \label{concent55}
  \begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{5}{d{1.6}} @{}}
     \toprule
     & & \multicolumn{5}{c@{}}{insti after 1990} \\
     \cmidrule{3-7}
     & & \mc{1} & \mc{2} & \mc{3} & \mc{4} & \mc{5} \\
     \multirow{5}{*}{concent} 
     & 1 & 0.06552  & 0.048739 & 0.029772 & 0.031109 & 0.027277 \\
     & 2 & 0.011051 & 0.058263 & 0.037196 & 0.040717 & 0.040017 \\
     & 3 & 0.106115 & 0.048928 & 0.067627 & 0.046418 & 0.046278 \\
     & 4 & 0.214212 & 0.032606 & 0.064722 & 0.040077 & 0.04908  \\
     & 5 & 0.068077 & 0.070491 & 0.058308 & 0.062065 & 0.051358 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx all the same